# Order of Run command in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Obviously to talk to a server you would have to first send a request to the server, then recieve the response. However it appears in this code that you first recieve the response then in the next line send the request -- what is going on here?

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onreadystatechange` is just a *listener* that runs when the request resolves.

Imagine your friend is helping you collect mail at the post office. You tell him:

> "Whenever a worker gives you the package, check the name on the package is correct, then open it, assemble the contents, and bring it back to me at my house. Now, go to the post office!"

You've told your friend what to do when he gets your mail, and *then* you sent him out to go collect it.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't receive the response first, it just sets up what to do *when* the response is received (which is *never* immediately, as this is an asynchronous operation). The order here actually doesn't matter.